# autodek forge. How can I blur objects other than the selected one?

Tags: autodesk-forge

I found the dbid using the search API.
And I used select API.
How can I blur objects other than the selected one?
Like the photo I posted.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRah1.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NOP_VIEWER.impl.highlightObjectNode(NOP_VIEWER.model,dbid,true)
```

And to undo try:

```
NOP_VIEWER.impl.highlightObjectNode(NOP_VIEWER.model,dbid,false)
```